# Для ссылок не меняется margin-top

Tags: html, css

```css
.con {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 1480px;
  margin: 100px 20px;
  border: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #FF5733;
  overflow: auto;
}

.film {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 80px 70px;
}

.iM {
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="film">
    <a class="iM" href="">In her eyes</a>
    <img src="assets/images/2.jpg" onclick="open()" class="im2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожулуйста: [ask] / [mcve]

Comment: `display: block` для ссылки

Answer (score 4):

**Вопрос:** Почему для ссылок не применяется свойство `margin-top`?

**Ответ:** Свойство `margin` может не работать в некоторых случаях. Например, в вашем случае оно не работает потому, что ссылка является строчным элементом.

**Решение:** Ссылку сделать блочным элементом. Для этого в CSS для ссылки указать свойство: `display: block;` или `display: flex;`. Пример:

```css
.con {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 1480px;
  margin: 100px 20px;
  border: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #FF5733;
  overflow: auto;
}

.film {
  margin: 80px 70px;
}

.iM {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="film">
    <a class="iM" href="">In her eyes</a>
    <img src="assets/images/2.jpg" onclick="open()" class="im2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну все-таки лучше сделать строчно-блочной)

Comment: Странно, у меня работает...) Все-равно + поставил)